# Change select dropdown icon padding bootstrap

Tags: html, css, vue.js, bootstrap-5

Currently I'm working with bootstrap and I have this select field. I was wondering if it's possible to change the padding of the dropdown icon, since it's too close to the border. So far I was only able to change the padding of the text on the left.

[UI result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HzFsz.png)

```
<select
        :disabled="identifierSelectDisabled"
        class="form-control pl-2 border-0 w-60"
        name="identifier"
        v-model="identifier"
        id="identifier"
        data-cy="identifier"
        required
      >
        <option
          v-for="palmSecureIdentifier in palmSecureEnrollIdentifiers"
          :key="palmSecureIdentifier.id"
          v-bind:value="palmSecureIdentifier"
          v-bind:label="palmSecureIdentifier.description"
        >
          {{ palmSecureIdentifier.description }}
        </option>
      </select>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) of the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  We cannot help you if you do not provide any code - see how to create a [MCVE]